# Можно ли контенту псевдоэлемета css задать повторение?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, вёрстка

Допустим, есть код:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  background: blueviolet;
  height:100px;
}

div:before {
  content: 'продано';
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Хочу заполнить весь див одинаковым элементом, чтобы было так:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  background: blueviolet;
  height: 100px;
}

div:before {
  content: 'продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано продано ';
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Можно ли контенту задать что-то вроде repeat-content, чтобы не писать все повторения вручную? К тому же размер дива заранее неизвестен.

UPD Хотелось бы получить кроссбраузерное решение.

Comment: не видно ничего подходящего именно для свойства content. Но можно сделать background с текстом и ему уже поставить repeat

Comment: text-shadow, но это жесть.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

С css-переменными [можно](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables) довольно быстро увеличивать контент (удвоение на каждую переменную):

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  background: blueviolet;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div:before {
  --a: "продано";
  --b: var(--a) " " var(--a);
  --c: var(--b) " " var(--b);
  --d: var(--c) " " var(--c);
  --e: var(--d) " " var(--d);
  --f: var(--e) " " var(--e);
  --g: var(--f) " " var(--f);
  --h: var(--g) " " var(--g);
  
  content: var(--h);
  color: white;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Кстати, можно заметить, что такое удвоение по сути даёт нечто типа двоичной системы счисления, что позволяет точно задать число повторений. Например, для 21 повторения надо использовать 16 + 4 + 1:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  background: blueviolet;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div:before {
  --a: "продано";                /*  1 */
  --b: var(--a) " " var(--a);    /*  2 */
  --c: var(--b) " " var(--b);    /*  4 */
  --d: var(--c) " " var(--c);    /*  8 */
  --e: var(--d) " " var(--d);    /* 16 */
  
  content: var(--e) " " var(--c) " " var(--a);
  color: white;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Ну и, конечно же, можно вместо двоичной использовать любую другую подходящую систему. Для тех же 21 можно сделать (3 * 2 + 1) * 3:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  background: blueviolet;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div:before {
  --a: "продано";                                /*  1 */
  --b: var(--a) " " var(--a) " " var(--a);       /*  3 */
  --c: var(--b) " " var(--b) " " var(--a);       /*  7 */
  
  content: var(--c) " " var(--c) " " var(--c);   /* 21 */
  color: white;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Эко вас, батенька, зацепила тема xDDDD

Comment: @MedvedevDev, ну они же разные :) Теперь главное чтоб никто 4 плюса сразу не ставил, а то автоотмена сработать может :(

Comment: @kizoso, дописал про число повторений :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, занятно, наглядно, классно!)

Answer (score 20):

Полная жесть с использованием `text-shadow`:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  background: blueviolet;
  height: 100px;
}

div:before {
  content: 'продано';
  color: white;
  text-shadow:
    8ch 0 0 white, 16ch 0 0 white, 24ch 0 0 white, 32ch 0 0 white, 40ch 0 0 white, 48ch 0 0 white, 56ch 0 0 white, 64ch 0 0 white, 72ch 0 0 white, 80ch 0 0 white,
    0 1.5em 0 white, 8ch 1.5em 0 white, 16ch 1.5em 0 white, 24ch 1.5em 0 white, 32ch 1.5em 0 white, 40ch 1.5em 0 white, 48ch 1.5em 0 white, 56ch 1.5em 0 white, 64ch 1.5em 0 white, 72ch 1.5em 0 white, 80ch 1.5em 0 white,
    0 3em 0 white, 8ch 3em 0 white, 16ch 3em 0 white, 24ch 3em 0 white, 32ch 3em 0 white, 40ch 3em 0 white, 48ch 3em 0 white, 56ch 3em 0 white, 64ch 3em 0 white, 72ch 3em 0 white, 80ch 3em 0 white,
    0 4.5em 0 white, 8ch 4.5em 0 white, 16ch 4.5em 0 white, 24ch 4.5em 0 white, 32ch 4.5em 0 white, 40ch 4.5em 0 white, 48ch 4.5em 0 white, 56ch 4.5em 0 white, 64ch 4.5em 0 white, 72ch 4.5em 0 white, 80ch 4.5em 0 white;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Изврат, но классно )))

Comment: @MedvedevDev, я уже более короткий изврат придумал)))

Comment: @Qwertiy А можете пояснить, пожалуйста, за счёт чего это работает?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, это просто тени - одно слово написано, а остальные слова - это его тени того же цвета.

Answer (score 16):

Гораздо меньшая жесть с фильтром `drop-shadow`: он позволяет удваивать контент каждым вызовом). Однако, пришлось прописать `display: block`, чтобы оно верно рендерилось:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  background: blueviolet;
  height: 100px;
}

div:before {
  content: 'продано';
  color: white;
  display: block;
  filter: 
    drop-shadow(8ch 0 0 white)
    drop-shadow(16ch 0 0 white)
    drop-shadow(32ch 0 0 white)
    drop-shadow(64ch 0 0 white)
    drop-shadow(0 1.5em 0 white)
    drop-shadow(0 3em 0 white);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 10):

Решение только для Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/element

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  background: red; /* если решение ниже не поддерживается, блок останется красным */
  background: -moz-element(#src) blueviolet;
  background: element(#src) blueviolet;
  height: 100px;
}

#src {
  position: absolute;
  top: -2em;
}

#src:before {
  content: 'продано\A0';
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<span id="src"></span>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Нет, в стандартах нет такого свойства, просто потому, что `:before` не для этого предназначен.
Если не хотите использовать JS, то можно прописать `overflow: hidden;` и `content: attr(data-bg-text);`. Затем создать спрятанный div где-нибудь в конце документа и прописать свойство `data-bg-text` со значением 'продано продано ... и так до посинения'. Но думаю, что такой вариант вызовет только боль.
Так что ответ: нет.

Answer (score 4):

Можно использовать `javascript`

Вот пример:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  background: blueviolet;
  height: 216px;
}

div:before {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <script>
    var s = "продано ";

    for (var i = 1; i <= 108; ++i) {

      document.write(s);

    }
  </script>

</div>
```

Comment: 1. Javascript никто не просил. 2. Псевдоэлемент тут где? 3. `document.write` не нужен. 4. Даже стили на вопрос не похожи. 5. Форматировать код кто будет?

Comment: А мне нравится ответ, может автор и не просил в явную ответ с JavaScript, но саму задачу он явно решает, а автор мог не просить потому что и не знал про возможность такого решения.